# Is there a way to validate asm.js code

Tags: javascript, validation, asm.js

I was hoping to spot compilation messages in Firefox Nightly but it does not happen. Is there a special switch for this?

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested it but there seems to be a validator in [here](https://github.com/dherman/asm.js/blob/master/lib/asm.js).

A quick look in the tests hints that it can be used as follows:

```
var asm = require('asm.js');

try {
  report = asm.validate(String(function f(stdlib, foreign, heap) {
    "use asm";

    // this is what we're validating
    function f() {
      var x = 0, y = 0;
      x = ((x|0)%(y|0))|0;
    }

    return {};
  }));

  console.log('Validated!');
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: I also found that one, but dosen't say validator anywhere in the project's description. also couldn't find any example how to use it.

Comment: The code looks well structured at first glance. Shouldn't be too difficult to figure out how it works.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. I'm still hoping for some secret switch for firefox though. :)

Comment: I guess it requires Node :-/

Comment: I'm getting `Error: Cannot find module 'asm.js'`. Even after an `npm install -g` as root (which seemed successful).

Comment: You don't need to install it globally, just do `npm install asm.js --save-dev`. And to use it in your code: `var asm = require('asm.js');`

Comment: Successfully ran the package. For your example I get `Error: Line 1: Unexpected token var`. The sample code from http://ejohn.org/blog/asmjs-javascript-compile-target/ gives: `ValidationError: invalid expression` plus a stack trace in both cases. - Even is best-case scenario this tool has a one-bit output (success/failure). The bigger problem is that it fails on the sample code which I'm sure should pass.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I find it kinda troubling though that the official example fails to validate: http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#putting-it-all-together

Answer (score 2):

You can check that it compiles, in the Web Console: Given a page with "use asm" in a module, it should give:

`Error: successfully compiled asm.js code (total compilation time 0ms)`

or, an actual error about why it couldn't compile to asm.